# Circle packing matrix with consistent scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization, circle-pack

I have had mixed results when combining for loops with d3 visuals; in this case it seems to be the most straight-forward solution to have a matrix of circle packs. However, one problem is that if I create the visual this way, the output can be slightly misleading. In the snippet below you will notice that the biggest circle in the third circle pack (152) looks just as big as the biggest circle in the first circle pack (200). So in its current form, the circle packs just reflect the proportions, and the changes in absolute size are not portrayed.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 1080;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
[
{'id':'1Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'1Q19','size':29.5},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':11},
{'id':'single','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':200}
  ],

  [
  {'id':'2Q19'},
  {'id':'pooled','parentId':'2Q19','size':31},
  {'id':'spv','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':15},
  {'id':'single','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':171}
],

[
{'id':'3Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'3Q19','size':28},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':12},
{'id':'single','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':152}
],

[
{'id':'4Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'4Q19','size':25},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':214},
{'id':'single','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':101}
],
];

var colorMap = {
  '1Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '2Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '3Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '4Q19':"#e7eef8",
  'pooled':"#f6d18b",
  'spv':"#366092",
  'single':"#95b3d7"
};

var strokeMap = {
  "pooled":"#000",
  "single":"#000",
  "spv":"#fff"
};

for (var j=0; j <(data.length); j++) {

  var vData = d3.stratify()(data[j]);

  var vLayout = d3.pack().size([250, 250]);

  var vRoot = d3.hierarchy(vData).sum(function (d) { return d.data.size; });
  var vNodes = vRoot.descendants();
  vLayout(vRoot);

  var thisClass = "circ"+String(j);

  var vSlices = graphGroup.selectAll('.'+thisClass).data(vNodes).attr('class',thisClass).enter().append('g');

  //console.log(vNodes)

  vSlices.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
      return d.x+(j*300)
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', function (d) { return d.r; })
  .style('fill', function(d) { return colorMap[d.data.id]});

  vSlices.append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d,i) {return d.x+(j*300)})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y+5})
  .attr('text-anchor','middle')
  .style('fill', function(d) {return strokeMap[d.data.id]})
  .text(function(d) {return d.data.data.size ? d.data.data.size : null});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

How can I establish a baseline/uniform scale for each of my circle packs in the circle pack matrix? I want the background/overall parent circle to be the same size, but the child circles to factor in absolute values in the packing process.

**Note:** I'm content with there being more empty space in the circle pack; perhaps in some instances the diameters may not fully span the parent circle. As long as the circles are tangent, the overall aesthetic theme should carry through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're using a loop to create elements in a D3 code is quite problematic, that's true... however, that's not the problem here. Let's see what you said:

> I want the background/overall parent circle to be the same size, but the child circles to factor in absolute values in the packing process [...] I'm content with there being more empty space in the circle pack.

Well, unfortunately, that's **not** how a circle packing works. What you have right now is the **correct** data visualisation: the leaves would have different sizes, even if they have the same value, depending on the values of the other leaves. A circle packing is a dynamic process/algorithm.

That being said, my suggestion is: leave it as it is (but fix that cumbersome loop).

However, even if I disagree (from a dataviz point) with your request, here is a solution. Set a square root scale:

```
var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
  .domain([0,250])
  .range([0,125]);
```

And pass the `size` values to `pack.radius`:

```
var vLayout = d3.pack().size([250, 250])
    .radius(function(d){
        return radiusScale(d.data.data.size)
    });
```

And here is the result:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 1200;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

const radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
  .domain([0,250])
  .range([0,125]);

  var data = [
[
{'id':'1Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'1Q19','size':29.5},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':11},
{'id':'single','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':200}
  ],

  [
  {'id':'2Q19'},
  {'id':'pooled','parentId':'2Q19','size':31},
  {'id':'spv','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':15},
  {'id':'single','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':171}
],

[
{'id':'3Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'3Q19','size':28},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':12},
{'id':'single','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':152}
],

[
{'id':'4Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'4Q19','size':25},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':214},
{'id':'single','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':101}
],
];

var colorMap = {
  '1Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '2Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '3Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '4Q19':"#e7eef8",
  'pooled':"#f6d18b",
  'spv':"#366092",
  'single':"#95b3d7"
};

var strokeMap = {
  "pooled":"#000",
  "single":"#000",
  "spv":"#fff"
};

for (var j=0; j <(data.length); j++) {

  var vData = d3.stratify()(data[j]);

  var vLayout = d3.pack().size([250, 250])
  .radius(function(d){
  return radiusScale(d.data.data.size)
  });

  var vRoot = d3.hierarchy(vData).sum(function (d) { return d.data.size; });
  var vNodes = vRoot.descendants();
  vLayout(vRoot);

  var thisClass = "circ"+String(j);

  var vSlices = graphGroup.selectAll('.'+thisClass).data(vNodes).attr('class',thisClass).enter().append('g');

  //console.log(vNodes)

  vSlices.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
      return d.x+(j*(j === 3 ? 320 : 310))
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', function (d) { return d.r; })
  .style('fill', function(d) { return colorMap[d.data.id]});

  vSlices.append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d,i) {return d.x+(j*(j === 3 ? 320 : 310))})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y+5})
  .attr('text-anchor','middle')
  .style('fill', function(d) {return strokeMap[d.data.id]})
  .text(function(d) {return d.data.data.size ? d.data.data.size : null});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the fact that, in the last pack, the overall circle is not the same size (it's bigger). Being the same size is simple impossible, given the packing logic.